# What's the difference between the Password Vault and the Credential Manager in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, credentials, passwordvault

I'm using the CredentialPicker class in order to present [a familiar UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKTHc.png). This, as expected, stores a credential in the Credential Manager of Windows. EDIT: sample code [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Credential-picker-sample-30fcba2e)

However, the recommended way to store username/passwords seems to be the PasswordVault API - [Best practice for saving sensitive data in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052482/best-practice-for-saving-sensitive-data-in-windows-8) - which looks like a different system altogether?

What is the correct way to both 1. present the familiar UI and 2. add, access and remove username/ passwords in a metro-style app?

I'm using C#, but C++ and JS answers would be fine..

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a Settings Pane to put your login fields into.
2. Use the PasswordVault to store the credentials for your app.
3. Take a look at this sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PasswordVault-f01be74a

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Credential-picker-sample-30fcba2e puts a credential in this: http://i.imgur.com/UfoTp.png with this UI http://i.imgur.com/lwPS6.png . This looks like the "official" way of doing it - Microsoft use this UI in the mail, people, calendar apps and more. Putting username/ pass fields in a settings pane seems like a hack.

Comment: I agree with this advice. In my experience, `CredentialPicker` is buggy, difficult to use and very slow.