# App Password for Windows Store App

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm developing an App which should have a Login, so the user has to authenticate itself every time he uses the app.
The app should not require the user to have an connection to the network; the password is device/user-specific.

Is there a common way how to save the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some links, which might be useful to you.

[Best practice for saving sensitive data in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052482/best-practice-for-saving-sensitive-data-in-windows-8)

[Managing user info (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br229572.aspx)

[Using PasswordVault to securely store passwords in WinRT](http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/using-passwordvault-to-securely-store-passwords-in-winrt/)

[CryptoWinRT sample (This sample shows how to use the new Cryptography APIs.)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CryptoWinRT-54ff3d9f)

Comment: Thank you for that! I saw the PasswordVault before, problem would be that anyone could open the credential manager from control panel. So the app would be open to anyone knowing this.

Comment: Then you can user Cryptography. Save password in Local Setting in encrypted form. I have updated the answer.